# Changing another Process Locale

Tags: process

From my own "key logger like" process I figured out that another process Locale is wrong (i.e. by sniffing few keys, I figured out that the foreground process Locale should be something while it is set to another). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: We have no idea what OS or platform you're using.  Without specific details, you're not going to get useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [setLocale](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Setting-the-Locale.html) from within that process to change it, and notify the process about this with some form of IPC like:

- [signals](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Signal-Handling.html)
- [sockets](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sockets.html)
- [pipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libc/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html)

from the process who knows

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify operating system or anything, but in Linux this is quite hard unless the target process is willing to help (i.e. there's some IPC mechanism available where you can ask the process to do it for you)

What you *can* do is to attach to the process, like a debugger or strace does, and the call the appropriate system call (like `setlocale()`)

The result on the target process is of course undetermined since it probably doesn't expect to get its locale changed under its feet :)